# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when creating an object with Generics, Protocols and Inheritance in Swift

Tags: inheritance, swift, protocols, swift-playground, generics

This code produces a EXC_BAD_ACCESS (even in playground).

(I simplified my code for better understanding.)

Preparation:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

protocol EmptyInit {
    init();
}

class FirstBase {

}


class SecondBase : EmptyInit {
    required init(){

    }
}

class A : FirstBase, EmptyInit{
    required override init(){

    }
}

class B : SecondBase, EmptyInit {
    required init() {

    }
}
```

It's obvious that you can create an instance of `A` and `B` like that.

```
A();
B();
```

Let's assume that there is a need for creating an instance of a class inside a function with Generics:

```
func creation<T: EmptyInit>(x a:T.Type) -> T{
    var object = T()
    return object;
}
```

While this code is working:

```
var b = creation(x: B.self);
```

this code crashes with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
var a = creation(x: A.self);
```

[link to the screenshot of the playground](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/837211/5780211/ff30a7ec-9da8-11e4-9c41-aed157aa7727.png)

This is weird, isn't it? I don't get it. Any ideas? (Maybe even a Swift bug?)

Comment: I also put it on the [Apple Dev Forum](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/259752).

Comment: What if you would omit "override" in your class A implementation?

Comment: Doesn't compile. Error message is: Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update Swift 1.2 XCode 6.3 Beta 2 (Beta 1 will not work):
Your code now runs without any problems and the expected result:

```
var b = creation(x: B.self); //{__lldb_expr_9.SecondBase}
var a = creation(x: A.self); //{__lldb_expr_11.FirstBase}
```

---

They conflict because FirstBase has no init but EmptyInit a required init.
This way it will work:

```
protocol EmptyInit {
    init();
}

class FirstBase {
    required init(){

    }
}


class SecondBase : EmptyInit {
    required init(){

    }
}

class A : FirstBase, EmptyInit{
    required init(){

    }
}

class B : SecondBase, EmptyInit {
    required init() {

    }
}

A();
B();


func creation<T: EmptyInit>(x a:T.Type) -> T{
    var object = T()
    return object;
}

var b = creation(x: B.self); // SecondBase
var a = creation(x: A.self); // FirstBase
```

Comment: I had the same issue .. and this solved it in may case

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean your answer as a workaround? I actually don't see a reason why FirstBase should implement the init() {}. Despite to avoid the crash ;-) Do I miss something?

Comment: `FirstBase` has to implement it because `Class A` shall conform to the Protocol `EmptyInit`. To conform to the protocol it must implement the init wanted by the protocol with the `required` attribute. But well it can not because it then would conflict with `FirstBase` which it inherits from. You can't use a `required init` deriving from a class which does not have a `required init` by it's own.

Comment: An it makes sense: The protocol wants to make sure that a init is used. So if a class wants to conform to a protocol and this init requirement it has to implement that init. If it now also derives from another class it is a logical must that you make sure that this class also uses this requred initializer. Otherwise you could not make sure that the init is used.

Comment: Sorry for not understanding :-) But what if the class FirstBase is not under your control. Does that mean that you cannot inherit from that class if it not conforms to the protocol? So the protocol requires implementation up and down the inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: Again. I also fixed my problem that way. But I still think it's only a workaround. If it would be correct this would mean, that if FirstBase is not under your control you can never extend this class in a way you want. Anyway: I got an email from apple. They think that this issue will be resolved in Xcode 6.3 beta 2. Unfortunately I cannot update atm. Will check (probably in a VM) and then post an update again

Comment: @helllth i have no problem with calling it a workaround. With "and it makes sense" i wanted to express that you can decipher why it does not work atm, though it most likely won`t stay this way. As a couple of other things related to generics. Though Swift 1.2 in XCode 6.3 shows the same bahaviour (tested).

Comment: Oh wait, i did not check in Beta 2 from yesterday but Swift 1.2 from Beta 1. I will report back if something changed.

Comment: I updated my answer with the result from Swift 1.2 XCode 6.3 Beta 2

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from Apple:

"We believe this issue has been addressed in the latest Xcode 6.3 beta 2, including iOS 8.3 SDK with Swift 1.2."

<strike>Cannot update atm. Will check (probably in a VM) and then post an update again.</strike>

Alex tested it. And it seems that Apple fixed the bug. Thanks Alex